# How to use one date picker for two textfield?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

I follow this [link](http://www.springtiger.co.uk/2010/08/18/open-uipickerview-when-user-enters-textfield/) but I have two textfield

How I use for two textfield.My code is [here](http://pastie.org/7938232#2,5) Date1 and Date2 are textfields.Here when I select date from textfield1 and textfield2 , textfield1 always takes value from textfield2

Answer (score 0):

You need to set tag on every text field and then identify in `donButtonPressed` method and set text according to tag.

Otherwise

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   if([textField isEqual:Date1])
   {
         Date1.text=@"YourDate";
   }
   else
   {
         Date2.text=@"YourDate";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use **textFieldDelegate** for this. have add the below code in viewcontroller.h file.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Once you did editing in textfield2, the below method.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
textField1.text=textField2.text;
```

}

use this

```
dateTextField1.text = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[datePicker date] dateStyle:kCFDateFormatterShortStyle timeStyle:kCFDateFormatterNoStyle];

    // Time    
dateTextField2.text = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[datePicker date] dateStyle:kCFDateFormatterNoStyle timeStyle:kCFDateFormatterShortStyle];
```

So, textField1 always takes value from textField2.

Comment: I means it is mistake for me.I dont want first textfield takes from second textfield.I want to fix that :) When I select 20.05.2013 from first,21.05.2013 from second output is date1:21.05.2013 date2:21.05.2013

Comment: what ever add some calculation in first textfielddidentediting method.

Comment: you are changing textfield2 value corresponding to textfield 1?. (e.g) it may be something increase one hour or one day?....

Comment: No I want to use my date picker for 2 textfield.I select 2 dates from textfield. (e.g) I want to select 19.05.2013 from first, 21.05.2013 from second.I use this for sending soap call.Is it clear ? There is a mistake in my code.Does not working for select different date

Comment: My problem  is : I selected 15.05.2013 from first textfield and selected 21.05.2013 from second textfield.Ouput Log : date1:21.05.2013,date2:21.05.2013

Comment: @Bharati D do you understand my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

To do that i always set a current TextField to know the textField. Then I use the currentTextField to modify the text when the pickerDate is validing by the user.

I don't need to use the textFieldDidEndEditing...

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   _activeTextField = textField;
}
```

Here you set equals the both textfield... That's why you edit Date1 and Date2 when you validate your date picker.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    Date1 = textField;
    Date2 = textField;
```